# Using transformer but masking in reverse direction/smart sampling for desired final word?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer

I'm trying to generate rhymes, so it would be very helpful to have a language model where I could input a final word, and have it output a sequence of words that ends with that word.

I could train my own model and reverse the direction of the mask, but I was wondering if there was any way I could use a pretrained model but apply a different mask to achieve this goal.

If this isn't possible, what's the best way to sample a forward-predicting model to achieve the highest probability sentence ending with a particular word?

Thanks!

Comment: What the particular final word depend on? Does that depend on previous sequences? Or previous words?

Comment: @pedrum It depends on the previous sentence.  It's exactly like the usual transformer case except predicting from right to left instead of left to right